# make css background image responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css

i use a image as a background of a class in left side with white background. the width of class is 1368px and image size is 392px or height 600px, i want to fix this image in left side of this class as responsive. i set this image in left side but in responsive page is not work correctly because only image showing in responsive device like in screen size 700px. how i solve this issue please help me. 
thanks a lot

```css
.about-middle { 
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto; 
    max-width: 1368px; 
    background: url(../images/right-side.jpg) left #fff; 
    overflow: auto; 
    max-height: 603px; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover; 
    -moz-background-size: cover;  
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

this is my code for this

Comment: Show some markup and make a fiddle.

Comment: Is it working with larger(high resolution) images?

Comment: Your code works. Try it at JSFiddle

Comment: but not work in responsive. i want to make also as responsive with screen size@Schlenderman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is js fiddle try for your request :

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/b5w1yb36/8/)

**Styles :**

```
.main {
   padding:50px 0; 
   position:absolute; 
   top:0; 
   bottom:0; 
   left:0; 
   right:0;
   background-color : blue;
   color : white;    
}
.inner {
    width : 30%;
    float:right;
    height:30%;
    background-color : red;
    background: url('http://www.w3blender.com/codecanyon/bgstretcher/sample-images/sample-4.jpg') no-repeat scroll left center / 100% 100% rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color : white;  
}
.fixedpos {
    width : 200px;
    float:left;
    height:200px;
    background-color : red;
    background: url('http://www.w3blender.com/codecanyon/bgstretcher/sample-images/sample-4.jpg') no-repeat scroll left center / 100% 100% rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color : white;  
}
```

**Html :**

```
<div class="main">
    main div
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="inner">
        responsive
    </div>
    <div class="fixedpos">
        fixed pos
    </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have to use `background: url(../images/right-side.jpg) no-repeat scroll left center / 81% 100% rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` in your background. And change the value of `x(81%)` with your screen size.